# Git Clone on LAN from Windows to Ubuntu Server

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, ssh

So I have been working on a project for some time on a Windows workstation, tracking the development via git. Now I need to move said project to an Ubuntu server on the LAN, and this has been proving to be a major pain. I've logged into the Ubuntu server using SSH, and trying to clone the project from the windows machine. However, I keep running into the same error message:

> fatal: '___' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

I've tried multiple variations of protocols and URI's, but the result is always the same. I don't know what's wrong, and I'm not sure where to look for reference / getting more debug info. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, as I'm really spinning my wheels here and going nowhere.

Here are some additional points that might or might not be relevant:

- The windows machine is running an open-ssh server on cygwin, however I also installed msysgit. I get the  feeling that this may be a problem.
- I was encountering "bash: git-upload-pack: command not found". I was able to get around this by placing "--upload-pack "
- I don't think that the repository I was working with on the Windows machine was initialized as a bare repository.
- The directory that I am cloning the code into is owned by the same user in the URI of the git clone command.

ADDENDUM:
Here is an example of a command I used on the Ubuntu server:

```
git clone --upload-pack "c:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack" "ssh://username@ipaddress/cygdrive/c/Users/username/.../projectname.git"
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct path?  If it's a cygwin ssh server, you'll have to use cygwin paths.  For example, `/cygdrive/c/my_git_repo` or something of that type

Comment: I tried all sorts of cygwin paths such as /cygdrive/c/..., and /c/..., with the first slash, without the first slash, in scp style, using https or git or ssh. I don't think the paths are the problem, but judging by my performance so far I don't think my thinking matters :(

Comment: Can you share your actual command line?  If so, it would be good to edit your answer to include it

Comment: I did a move sort of like this and I wanted to avoid running any servers (including cygwin ssh server) on the Windows box, so I did it like this: create an empty repository on the new server (`mkdir repo.git;cd repo.git;git init`; you may want to add `--bare`), add the new repository as a remote in the existing repository inside cygwin (`git remote add origin ssh://user@host/~/repo.git`) and push everything to it (`git push --all -u ; git push --tags`)

Comment: @EricRenouf I added and addendum with the info you requested

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, I tried your method and it appeared to work, however the directory on the server is empty and I can't checkout the branches that have been added. I also can't fetch origin, and I receive the same error as in the question. git remote -v shows origin, but no url

Comment: In your example clone command, you're using `--upload-pack` to run the msysgit version of `git-upload-pack` inside of a cygwin-hosted ssh session. That seems like a really bad idea. msys git won't understand the `/cygdrive/` path which will be passed to it. If your cygwin git couldn't find its own `git-upload-pack`, that problem should be fixable in a better way. `/usr/bin/git-upload-pack` and `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack` should both work. I wonder about that cygwin ssh server - is it handing off a bad `$PATH`? Have you tested it with an interactive login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a few months since I used cygwin, but I recall having issues when using msysgit with cygwin. I preferred using the git version packaged for cygwin.

I think the simpler solution would be to `rsync` (or your preferred method of copying) the directory that contains your working directory and `.git` directory from windows to the ubuntu server.

Then on the ubuntu server you can create a bare repo using
`git clone --bare /path/to/rsync'd/directory/ /path/to/new/repo.git`

The reason that this should work is that the contents of the `.git` directory is the repo.

Comment: Yeah, I uninstalled msysgit and reinstalled cygwin with git and the clone went off without a hitch. Thanks.